# Phaser Pulling Data from Firebase and Loading it as a sprite

Tags: javascript, phaser

I am trying to pull img data from database to replace it with player sprite url.

```
    ionViewDidLoad() {
        this.profileData = this.fire.authState.switchMap(auth => this.db.object(`profile/${auth.uid}`).valueChanges());
        this.profileData.subscribe(profile =>{
        this.avatar = profile.avatar;
        console.log(this.avatar);//i got data(its an url string)

        });

        console.log('ionViewDidLoad ZombiePage');
        this.game = new Phaser.Game(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight, Phaser.AUTO, 'game', { preload: this.preload.bind(this), create: this.create.bind(this),update:this.update.bind(this),render:this.render.bind(this) });
    console.log(window.innerHeight);





      }

    preload(){
    console.log(this.avatar); //Undefined
this.game.load.image('player', this.avatar);
```

Why i cant reach data from preload function ? btw im using ionic/angular framework.i combined it with phaser.

Comment: Where are you storing the images, is it in fb storage (as an image), or in fb realtime database (as a dataURI string)?

Comment: its in fb realtime database its just an url dont really think it like image just a string

Comment: I guess i must wait for subscribe before loading preload but how to make it wait for subscribe ? I tried to add it into state then call state from subscribe but for example let gameState = { game functions here}; decleration to create state throws error  Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.